# Magento Security Patches showing "Unknown" status in Mage Report

Tags: magento-1.9, security, patches

I am keep **seeing the patches status is "unknown" in magereport**, but the patches are successfully installed in the site. I updated the patch codes in core controllers which are extended local/Mage Directory. Can anyone came across this problem.

Answer (score 2):

MageReport checks from the outside, because it cannot see your code. Sometimes checks will give an "unknown" result.

This is notably the case for a fully patched shop, because once patch 5994 is installed, it is not possible to determine the existence of patch 5344.

However, as patches must be applied in order, this is seldom a problem.

Reference: https://www.magereport.com/page/about

Comment: great you are helping on sunday also :-)

Answer (score 0):

The **Unknown** status regarding some of the patches is a good thing.

It means that the test MageReport is trying to do is unreachable.

> We were unable to conclusively check your shop. The check might have been blocked by other emergency measures you, or your provider, have taken.

Most likely you get this status when you changed your backend URL / Path for instance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Raphael, but my site admin path is not changed its admin only, will the magereport look for some exact changes on some exact files which they updated on Patch?

Comment: @Nagamani I'm not sure I'm not the developer of MageReport, feel free to contact them to find out ;)